# Sort by column for ndarray

Tags: rust, rust-ndarray

In rust, how do you efficiently sort an ndarray::Array2 by a particular column?

I am trying to sort an Array2 by a particular column of values, either ascending or descending.

Comment: Please provide an example of what you want. Right now it is a bit unclear what exactly you're after.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution using [`Vec::sort`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.sort):

```rust
use ndarray::Array2;

fn main() {
    let mut arr2 = Array2::<i32>::from(vec![[1,2,4,3], [3,4,1,9], [4,7,2,9]]);

    for mut column in arr2.rows_mut() {
        let mut vec = column.to_vec();
        vec.sort();
        
        for j in 0..column.shape()[0] {
            column[j] = vec[j];
        }
    }
    
    println!("{:#?}", arr2);
}
```

Here is the link to [RustExplorer](https://www.rustexplorer.com/b#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).

If you want to get rid of the extra `Vec`, I think you would have to implement the sort algorithm (like [Mergesort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort) yourself).

Comment: You misunderstand, this sorts each row/column individually and separately. I'm trying to sort the entire thing **by** a particular column.

Comment: Maybe you should edit your question and include sample input as well as the expected output, because in that case I do not really understand what you are trying to achieve.